# Why isnt next:hover turning the text red?

Tags: html, css

On the site http://gopiswrong.com    the class .next:hover should turn the text "What should GOPisWrong.com say next?" red on hover, but it does not. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an inline style with a `color` that needs getting rid of overriding the hover style:

```
<a class="next" style="margin-left:300px;font-family:sans-serif;color:#000000;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the "`color:#000000`" from the link's `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Because the color of the element is determined inside the style tag of the element itself. Remove that from the style tag, and put it into the stlyesheet and it should work fine.